# What is the "best" solution to $\int{\frac{1}{x^{2}-a^{2}}dx}$?

Tags: calculus, integration

I've often seen the solution of $\int{\frac{1}{x^{2}-a^{2}}}dx$ be given as
$$\frac{1}{2a}\ln{\left ( \frac{|x-a|}{|x+a|} \right )}$$
and
$$-\frac{1}{a}\mathrm{arctanh}\left({\frac{x}{a}}\right)$$

Looking at both graphs on desmos, the "arctanh" solution seems to be defined over the domain $\left\{ x \in \mathbb{R} | -a < x < a\right\}$ whereas the logarithmic solution seems to be defined over the domain $\left\{ x \in \mathbb{R} | x \notin \left\{-a, a \right\} \right\}$.

Since the logarithmic solution is defined over a greater domain, I would assume it would be preferred, however looking online I often see the "arctanh" solution being used instead.

Should one of these solutions be used in favour of the other or does it not matter?

Thanks.

Comment: If you wrote the second as $-\frac{1}{a}\text{arctanh}\left(\left|{\frac{x}{a}}\right|\right)$ then it would be the same as the first.

Comment: Then the choice is similar to $\int \frac1x \, dx = \log(x)+C$ or $=\log(|x|)+C$.

Comment: @Etemon yep, fixed my mistake. Thanks for pointing it out